# Concurrent query execution is slow in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

Concurrent query execution is slow in MySQL 5.7.

When I run only this below query it takes - 5.28sec

```
select pkid,lastname
    from Table1
    where pkid in (select fkid from Table2)
    order by 2 desc limit 10;
```

But if I fire the same query 10times concurrently, each query takes around 11secs.  Im not sure why its happening, even though my innodb_thread_concurrency is 10.

Concurrent execution stats - no_of_queries vs each_query_time:

```
1 time - 5.3sec
5 time - 7.8sec
10 times - 11sec
```

Variables:

```
max_connections - 1500
innodb_thread_concurrency - 10
```

Cpu - 16core

Can someone, guide me what I'm missing here.

Note: This is not query optimisation. My issue here is concurrent query execution is slow. Just to show the difference between executing a single query separately vs executing same query 10/5 items concurrently, I used this query.

Explain

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "1541542.63"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "sort_cost": "1.00"
      },
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "Table2",
            "access_type": "index",
            "possible_keys": [
              "Table2_FK4_IDX"
            ],
            "key": "Table2_FK4_IDX",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "FKID"
            ],
            "key_length": "9",
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1246072,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 732208,
            "filtered": "58.76",
            "using_index": true,
            "loosescan": true,
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "2586.21",
              "eval_cost": "146441.71",
              "prefix_cost": "149027.92",
              "data_read_per_join": "2G"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "TABLE2ID",
              "FKID"
            ],
            "attached_condition": "(`db1234`.`Table2`.`FKID` is not null)"
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "Table1",
            "access_type": "eq_ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY"
            ],
            "key": "PRIMARY",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "PKID"
            ],
            "key_length": "8",
            "ref": [
              "db1234.Table2.FKID"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "1246072.00",
              "eval_cost": "0.20",
              "prefix_cost": "1541541.63",
              "data_read_per_join": "19K"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "PKID",
              "LASTNAME"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think improving your query (to bring down the 5.28 sec to less than that), is the start of your solution, but more info is needed.  Can you share the DDL for table1 and table2, and the number of records in table2, and an average on the number of records in the result ?

Comment: that is completly normal: all processes have to share the same resources, and they are finite, so with every additional process you reduce the resources considerable, so the answers si make better queries, increase hardware resources

Comment: @nbk for reading the resources, mysql won't get exclusive lock i think. So everyone can read parallel-ly right?

Comment: your query has many problem alone Select * From table2 makes a full tbale scan and his for every query, you should read up how mysql handles data and try gordon query.

Comment: @nbk for me the issue is not query(just for an example i took this query). It's concurrent query time.  can your share more info reg this point which you said `all processes have to share the same resources`

Comment: When you ask for query optimization help, you should include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table in the query, so we don't have to guess at the columns, indexes, or constraints in your tables. Also include the output of `EXPLAIN <query>` is helpful.

Comment: @BillKarwin This is not query optimisation, this query was created just to show example between executing a single query separately vs executing same query 10 items concurrently. Btw updated explain.

Comment: OK, have you ever run more than one busy application on a single computer? They must share the CPU, RAM, disk I/O bandwidth. Each one can slow down the other. If you add more busy applications, they all slow down. This is common and predictable.

Comment: The key to improve this, is to make the query consume less resources per time so that concurrent instance have less of a chance to need the same resource at the same time and one has to wait on the resource. And that *is* query optimization!

Comment: @BillKarwin I understand that as far as this machine. I will make it little clear. No other request/queries comes in. Im the only one executing queries on it.  This is 16core and 256gb ram machine and my innodb_thread_concurrency is 10 which is less than 16core, which should be more than enough for executing atleast 5queries in parallel.  And this issue is reproducible only when two tables(either join/subquery) are in a query.

Comment: What do you suppose is the explanation of this?

Comment: How many rows in each table?  Did you try a simple JOIN to get the same results?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; something smells fishy.

Comment: Years ago a package was written to perform queries by chopping them up and running them in parallel.  The statistics provided for the package are consistent with what you are seeing (11/5.3) -- namely that the "parallel" threads were about 2 times as slow as you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

The queries are competing for resources to do the same thing.  They interfere with each other.

Perhaps if you wrote the query using `exists` and have the right indexes the whole thing would be faster:

```
select t1.pkid, t1.lastname
from Table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.fkid = t1.pkid)
order by 2 desc
limit 10;
```

You definitely want an index on `table2(fkid)` (although you get this for free with the `foreign key` declaration in MySQL).  It is possible than an index on `table1(lastname desc, pkid)` would also help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here FKid, is indexed. Just for explanation I took this query.  `The queries are computing for resources to do the same thing` can you explain this in detail / share information url reg this. Because I'm just reading here, where mysql won't get exclusive lock i think. So everyone thread can read parallel-ly right?

Comment: @vinieth . . . I didn't realize how close "computing" and "competing" are.  In any case, MySQL has had issues with optimizing `in` subqueries.  I recommend `exists` with an index.

Comment: Okay you can ignore suqbuery. But for a join query also same issue reproducible `select pkid,lastname from Table1 inner join Table2 on pkid = fkid order by 2 desc limit 10;`  this query was created just to show example between executing a single query separately vs executing same query 10 items concurrently. And this parallel execution issue is reproducible only when two tables(either join/subquery) are in a query

Comment: And jfyi I checked exits with index takes 42sec for that query, where as subquery which used loosescan semijoin was faster. Btw the issue here is not query optimisation. Concurrent execution is slower..

Comment: @vinieth . . . And that is with the index?

Comment: Yes with  index Table2_FK4_IDX(FKID) which is in the Key column of explain .